# android project not working on emulator

Tags: android

My code seems fine, I don't see any sort of bugs. When I run the code and hit build the emulator rejects my app.

How can I make the emulator accept my code ?

```js
package com.example.abdiqani.guess;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int points = 0;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pickNumbers();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void pickNumbers() {
        Button lbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LeftButton);
        Button rbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RightButton);
        Random randy = new Random();
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        while (num1 == num2) {
            num1 = randy.nextInt(10);
            num2 = randy.nextInt(10);

        }
        lbutton.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
        rbutton.setText(String.valueOf(num2));

    }

    public void LeftButtonClick(View view) {
        if (num1 > num2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
            points++;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are STUPID!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
            points--;
        }
        TextView pointsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsView);
        pointsView.setText("Points: " + points);
        pickNumbers();


    }

    public void RightButtonClick(View view) {
        if (num2 > num1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
            points++;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are STUPID!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
            points--;
        }
        TextView pointsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsView);
        pointsView.setText("Points: " + points);
        pickNumbers();
    }
```

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/Users/abdiqani/AndroidStudioProjects/guess/app/src/main/java/com/example/abdiqani/guess/MainActivity.java:70: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
1 error

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

```
Total time: 4 mins 53.144 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/Users/abdiqani/AndroidStudioProjects/guess/app/src/main/java/com/example/abdiqani/guess/MainActivity.java:70: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
1 error

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: post the full code of mainactivity

Comment: Your IDE should be complaining at you that you are missing a closing brace for MainActivity. Your code simply won't compile, so it's not the emulator's fault

Comment: I posted the code from mainactivity

Comment: am using android studio not eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add `}` at the end of your MainActivity

you actually forgot to add or accidently deleted it

Comment: I am repeating my request, does your problem i solved or not. please respond and post the present problem code with logcat if any